# (Pytorch) Why conv2d results are all different. Their data type is all integer, no float

Tags: pytorch, convolution

I've tried and compared three different methods for convolution computation with a custom kernel in Pytorch. Their results are different but I don't understand why that is.

Setup code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

inp = torch.arange(3*500*700).reshape(1,3,500,700).to(dtype=torch.float32)
wgt = torch.ones((1,3,3,3)).to(dtype=torch.float32)
stride = 1
padding = 0
h = inp.shape[2] - wgt.shape[2] + 1
w = inp.shape[3] - wgt.shape[3] + 1
```

##### Method 1

```
out1 = torch.zeros((1,h,w)).to(dtype=torch.float32)
for o in range(1):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(h):
            for k in range(w):
                out1[o,j,k] = out1[o,j,k] + (inp[0, i, j*stride:j*stride+3, k*stride:k*stride+3] * wgt[0,i]).sum()
out1 = out1.to(dtype=torch.int)
```

##### Method 2

```
inp_unf = F.unfold(inp, (3,3))
out_unf = inp_unf.transpose(1,2).matmul(wgt.view(1,-1).t()).transpose(1,2)
out2 = F.fold(out_unf, (h,w), (1,1))
out2 = out2.to(dtype=torch.int)
```

##### Method 3

```
out3 = F.conv2d(inp, wgt, bias=None, stride=1, padding=0)
out3 = out3.to(dtype=torch.int)
```

And here are the results comparison:

```
>>> h*w
347604

>>> (out1==out2).sum().item()
327338
>>> (out2 == out3).sum().item()
344026
>>> (out1 == out3).sum().item()
330797

>>> out1.shape
(1, 498, 698)
>>> out2.shape 
(1, 1, 498, 698)
>>> out3.shape
(1, 1, 498, 698)
```

Their data types are all `int` so floating point won't the result. When I use a squared input format such as `h=500` and `w=500`, all three results are all matching. But not for non-squared inputs, such as the one above with `h=500` and `w=700`. Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three results are cast to integer data types but keep in mind their computation is done with float32... It is often preferred to check equality between two tensors using [`torch.isclose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.isclose.html):

```
>>> torch.isclose(out1, out2).float().mean()
tensor(1.)

>>> torch.isclose(out2, out3).float().mean()
tensor(1.)

>>> torch.isclose(out1, out3).float().mean()
tensor(1.)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit and answer! I wish I'd give upvote but my reputation hasn't hit 15. Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem, the tick will do.